# How to prevent HttpListener from aborting pending requests on stoppage? HttpListener.Stop is not working

Tags: c#, async-await, abort, httplistener

I have a problem here. In below code the async/await pattern is used with HttpListener. When the request is sent via HTTP "delay" query string argument is expected and its value causes the server to delay the mentioned request processing for the given period. I need the server to process the pending requests even after the server stopped receiving new requests.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    HttpListener httpListener = new HttpListener();

    CountdownEvent sessions = new CountdownEvent(1);
    bool stopRequested = false;

    httpListener.Prefixes.Add("http://+:9000/GetData/");

    httpListener.Start();

    Task listenerTask = Task.Run(async () =>
    {
        while (true)
        {
            try
            {
                var context = await httpListener.GetContextAsync();

                sessions.AddCount();

                Task childTask = Task.Run(async () =>
                {
                    try
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine($"Request accepted: {context.Request.RawUrl}");

                        int delay = int.Parse(context.Request.QueryString["delay"]);

                        await Task.Delay(delay);

                        using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(context.Response.OutputStream, Encoding.Default, 4096, true))
                        {
                            await sw.WriteAsync("<html><body><h1>Hello world</h1></body></html>");
                        }

                        context.Response.Close();
                    }
                    finally
                    {
                        sessions.Signal();
                    }
                });
            }
            catch (HttpListenerException ex)
            {
                if (stopRequested && ex.ErrorCode == 995)
                {
                    break;
                }

                throw;
            }
        }
    });

    Console.WriteLine("Server is running. ENTER to stop...");

    Console.ReadLine();

    sessions.Signal();

    stopRequested = true;

    httpListener.Stop();

    Console.WriteLine("Stopped accepting requests. Waiting for the pendings...");

    listenerTask.Wait();

    sessions.Wait();

    Console.WriteLine("Finished");

    Console.ReadLine();

    httpListener.Close();
}
```

The exact problem here, is that when the server is stopped the HttpListener.Stop is called, but all the pending requests are aborted immediately, i.e. the code is unable to send the responses back.

In non-async/await pattern (i.e. simple Thread based implementation) I have a choice to abort the thread (which I suppose is very bad) and this will allow me to process pending requests, because this simply Aborts HttpListener.GetContext call.

Can you please point me out, what am I doing wrong and how to can I prevent HttpListener to abort pending requests in async/await pattern?

Comment: What I meant is I would like my server to stop receiving new requests and to be able to process pending requests. But calling HttpListener.Stop prevents me from responding to the pending requests. As for the CancellationToken in async/await scenario, how can this help me if HttpListener.GetContextAsync doesn't accept CancellationToken at all?

Comment: @Luaan, by the way, thank you, I have updated the text and the title of the question.

Comment: @Luaan, seems to be a bug. Couldn't force the HttpListener to pause receiving requests and to handle the pending ones. Even tried Begin/EndGetContext pair. Still no luck. Actually the Thread.Abort method helps, because it is able abort the call to the HttpListener.GetContext without stopping the request processing logic.

Comment: @Luaan, thanks again. I've got your point. It turned that the code working with Thread.Abort hid the point that HttpListener.GetContext hung and it woke back right after I called Thread.Stop.

Comment: Moved the comments to an answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that when `HttpListener` closes the request queue handle, the requests in progress are aborted. As far as I can tell, there is no way to avoid having `HttpListener` do that - apparently, it's a compatibility thing. In any case, that's how its `GetContext`-ending system works - when the handle is closed, the native method `GetContext` call to actually get the request context returns an error immediately.

`Thread.Abort` doesn't help - really, I've yet to see a place where `Thread.Abort` is used correctly outside of the "application domain unloading" scenario. `Thread.Abort` can only ever abort *managed* code. Since your code is currently running native, it will only be aborted when it returns back to managed code - which is almost exactly equivalent to just doing this:

```
var context = await httpListener.GetContextAsync();

if (stopRequested) return;
```

... and since there's no better cancellation API for `HttpListener`, this is really your only option if you want to stick with `HttpListener`.

The shutdown will look like this:

```
stopRequested = true;
sessions.Wait();

httpListener.Dispose();
listenerTask.Wait();
```

I'd also suggest using `CancellationToken` instead of a `bool` flag - it handles all the synchronization woes for you. If that's not desirable for some reason, make sure you synchronize access to the flag - contractually, the compiler is allowed to omit the check, since it's impossible for the flag to change in single-threaded code.

If you want to, you can make `listenerTask` complete sooner by sending a dummy HTTP request to yourself right after setting `stopRequested` - this will cause `GetContext` to return immediately with the new request, and you can return. This is an approach that's commonly used when dealing with APIs that don't support "nice" cancellation, e.g. `UdpClient.Receive`.

Comment: I have chosen a slightly different tactics. I am cancelling the cancellation token and then waiting for the pending requests without actually stopping receiving the new ones. If a new request arrives after the cancellation I'm simply aborting it, and for the cases when no additional request arrives and GetContextAsync hangs I'm eventually calling Stop and Close on HTTP listener.